# The first order condition of $\mathbb{E}[\zeta Z] - \ln \mathbb{E}[e^{Z}]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability

I want to calculate the first order condition of $f(Z) = \mathbb{E}[\zeta Z] - \ln \mathbb{E}[e^{Z}]$. Here $\zeta$ is a probability density function, with $\zeta \ge 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[\zeta] = 1$. $Z$ is a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random function in $L_p(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a probability space, $L_p$ is the $L_p$ space equiped with the $L_p$ norm.

I tried to calculate $f'(Z)$, since $\mathbb{E}[\zeta] = 1$, and $Z\in L_p$, by dominated converge theorem we can exchange the derivative and the expectation. Therefore,

$$ f'(Z) = \mathbb{E}[\zeta] - \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^Z]}{\mathbb{E}[e^Z]} = 0. $$
I get this weird expression, and it is definitely incorrect. The optimal solution should be $\hat{Z} = \ln \zeta + a$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$, and I could not figure out how to obtain it. Can any one give me some hints?

Comment: What is a derivative with respect to Z? Is it a functional derivative where e.g. d/dZ of E[g(Z)] would be g'(Z)? Can you now see what's going wrong?

Comment: I'm suspecting $\frac{d}{dZ} E[g(Z)] = E[\frac{d}{dZ} g(Z)]$, which is guaranteed because $Z \in L_p$.

Comment: $Z$ is a random variable, so you can't differentiate just like that. Instead, for arbitrary random variable $X$, consider the derivative "in the direction of $X$", i.e. $\frac{df(Z+tX)}{dt} \big|_{t=0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to define your functional $f$ on a space over which it is always finite; the smallest is $L_\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and the largest is called the *primal entropic space* (see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11579-017-0197-9) for definition, its dual and bidual spaces, and its relations to $L_p$ spaces).

Secondly, the Fréchet derivate of $f(Z) = \mathbb{E}[\zeta Z] - \ln \mathbb{E}[e^{Z}]$, denoted by $\nabla f(Z)$, exists and is given by

$$\nabla f(Z) = \zeta - \frac{e^{Z}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{Z}]}.$$

This can be obtained by finding the directional derivative below for direction $D$ and observing that  it is always linear in $D$:

$$f'_D(Z) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(Z+tD)-f(Z)}{t}=E\left(D\left(\zeta - \frac{e^{Z}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{Z}]}\right)\right).$$

Note that as $f$ is concave in $Z$, the global maximizer $Z^*$ of $f$ (if any) satisfies $\frac{e^{Z^*}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{Z^*}]}=\zeta$, i.e., $\nabla f(Z^*)=0$.

Comment: I now understand, thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderGrey you are very welcome!